# Проверка на переполнение

Tags: c++builder

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как для вот этой программы со строками сделать проверку на переполнение, и чтобы когда мы удаляли все слова, начинающиеся на гласную букву, компилятор выдавал оставшиеся слова, только чтобы в начале не было пробела.

```
stroka()
{
    char str[255], s[255];
    cout << "Input stroku:n";
    gets(str);
    char *stroka = new char[20];
    gets(stroka);
    OemToChar(stroka, s);
    cout << "n";

    char s1[255] = "aAeEiIoOuU", s2[255] = "";
    bool f;
    int i, j, k, b, n = 0, h = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(s)) {
    f = true;
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(s1); j++)
        if (s[i] == s1[j])
        f = false;
    if (f == false)
        if (i == 0 || s[i - 1] == ' ')
        while (s[i] != ' ')
            i++;
    if (f) {
        s2[h] = s[i];
        h++;
    } else if (s[i - 1] != ' ') {
        s2[h] = s[i];
        h++;
    };
    i++;
    }
    cout << "Otvet:n";
    cout << s2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверок на переполнение вместо gets() используйте fgets().

А у Вас компилятор не пишет такое сообщение ?

```
warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

Вместо просто while(s[i] != ' ') надо while (s[i] && s[i] != ' ') или, в конце концов, i сравнивайте с 255 (это у Вас размер s) и т.п.

Это понятно ?

--

Вообще, извините, программа выглядит как бред какой-то.

--

Задачку, хотя бы, нормально сформулировали. Что дано. Что требуется сделать. Как должен выглядеть результат. Что Вы сделали, что видите в результате и что не получается.